# Where is the chat link?

Tags: support

I have become irregular to this site for sometimes. Now that I returned, I found the site's look has changed astoundingly and the change is good! Although I abled to work out how the new look works, I can't really find the chat option here. So where has it gone and how to enter the chat rooms? Thanks and Merry Christmas!

Comment: I can see you got your answer. Refer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone/210187#210187) for New top bar quick reference guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to enter chatrooms is to go to the respective meta site and see the links on the right. But the "official" chat-link is reachable by opening the "StackExchange" pulldown menu in the upper left. Above the site list there are also links to "chat", "blog",...

Comment: Once you are used to it, the new layout is actually quite friendly.